# Moving from Picasa to Google Photos

Tags: picasa, google-photos

I was using Picasa to store my pictures and I used the api to retrieve them in my application.
Now Picasa is moving to Google Photos.
Every where I looked, it seems that Google Photos is using the same api as Picasa.
Am I correct in assuming that this means I don't have to do any changes to my application?
Will my application still display the correct images?

Additional quetsion:
I created a new account on Google Photos and created some albums.
Now I tried to connect to the Google Photos page with the Picasa Api and I keep getting page not found. Does anyone have an example of how to connect to the Google Photos with the Picasa Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Google photos is using the same API used by picasa. However there has been an announcement regarding changes to the API which will take into effect from may 1st 2016.

Announcement [Details](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/)

Comment: I found that as well. As I read it, I will still be able to use the picasa-api to do what I need. The other features, I don't use them. So that would mean, that I'm not going to have to make any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you will be able to access the images, but google will no longer support some functionalities like

- Flash support
- Community search
- Mutation operations other than uploads
- All support for tags, comments, and contacts

The API will still support other functions, including reading photos, reading albums, reading photos in albums, and uploading new photos. Although these operations will continue to be supported and the protocol will remain the same, the content included in the responses and the operation behavior may change.